# How group wpf controls and send group to method

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 2 buttons and they do the same on different controls. How can i make this better? Because now i too much copy/paste. Here is image and code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjiW1.png)

```
    private void button_ClickOld(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBoxOld.Text = SelectCatalog();
        if (File.Exists(TextBoxOld + ConfigFilePath))
        {
            GetClientProperty(TextBoxOld.Text);
            UpdateOldLabel();
        }
        else
        {
            LogsTextBox.AppendText("\nWrong folder selected - Config file doesn't exist");
        }
    }
    private void button_ClickNew(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBoxNew.Text = SelectCatalog();
        if (File.Exists(TextBoxNew + ConfigFilePath))
        {
            GetClientProperty(TextBoxNew.Text);
            UpdateNewLabel();
        }
        else
        {
            LogsTextBox.AppendText("\nWrong folder selected - Config file doesn't exist");
        }
    }
```

xaml

```
 <Button x:Name="ButtonOld" Content="..." HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="149,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="25" Click="button_ClickOld"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxOld" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="24,35,0,0" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    <Button x:Name="ButtonNew" Content="..." HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="447,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="25" Click="button_ClickNew"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxNew" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="322,35,0,0" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" IsReadOnly="True"/>` <Label x:Name="OldNameLabel" Content="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label x:Name="OldIpLabel" Content="IP" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label x:Name="OldWebpageUriLabel" Content="WebpageUri" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,130,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="OldConnectionStringTextBox" Text="ConnectionString" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,160,0,0" Width="120"
             VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Linen" BorderThickness="0" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    <Label x:Name="NewNameLabel" Content="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="322,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label x:Name="NewIpLabel" Content="IP" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="322,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label x:Name="NewWebpageUriLabel" Content="WebpageUri" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="322,130,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="NewConnectionStringTextBox" Text="ConnectionString" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="322,160,0,0" Width="120"
             VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Linen" BorderThickness="0" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    <Label x:Name="ArrowLabel" Content="&lt;-" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="221,14,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="30" />
    <Label x:Name="OldVersionTextBoxLabel" Content="Old Version:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,4,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label x:Name="NewVersionTextBoxLabel" Content="New Version:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="325,4,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of your it, you don't understand MVVM and SOLID principles. If you truly want to take advantage of WPF, you must first learn MVVM, and to truly take advantage of MVVM, you need to understand SOLID. To reduce the burden of verbose XAML and boiler plate code, you should take advantage of MVVM frameworks, Caliburn.Micro is super easy to use but require you to have a good architecture to be able to fully utilize it.

Further, using MVVM will make your XAML code so much simpler. Old Version and New Version section will just have one UserControl and may look like

```
<views:VersionView DataContext={Binding OldVersionViewModel}/>
<views:VersionView DataContext={Binding NewVersionViewModel}/>
```

You will save yourself a lot of pain and make you delighted you chose WPF for your UI once you learn the power of MVVM.

But if this is just a small project and you insist on using code behind, you can do

```
private void button_ClickOld(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SelectVerifyAndLog(TextBoxOld, UpdateOldLabel);
}

private void button_ClickNew(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SelectVerifyAndLog(TextBoxNew, UpdateNewLabel);
}

void SelectVerifyAndLog(TextBox textBox, Action updateLabel)
{
    textBox.Text = SelectCatalog();
    if (File.Exists(textBox + ConfigFilePath))
    {
        GetClientProperty(textBox.Text);
        updateLabel();
    }
    else
    {
        LogsTextBox.AppendText("\nWrong folder selected - Config file doesn't exist");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You can reuse your code

```
private void button_ClickOld(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ButtonHelper(TextBoxOld);
}
private void button_ClickNew(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ButtonHelper(TextBoxNew);
}
void ButtonsHelper(TextBox textBox) {
    TextBoxNew.Text = SelectCatalog();
    if (File.Exists(textBox + ConfigFilePath))
    {
        GetClientProperty(textBox.Text);
        UpdateNewLabel();
    }
    else
    {
        LogsTextBox.AppendText("\nWrong folder selected - Config file doesn't exist");
    }
}
```

2) In WPF, use MVVM, otherwise you just don't have advantages of WPF

3) If you have many groups of controls like you marked on your picture and they have much of code, make them controls. And each of them will contain it's own xaml, it's own code, and you can reuse it. It's not necessary to put all the xaml in one file.